# Make services accessible only from Private network Kubernetes

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I have received a public ip address for my kubernetes service which i can configure as a loadbalancer ip in my NGINX ingress. This public ip address can be accessed from public internet.

Is there a way or some configuration through which i can make these services accessible only from my client network in kubernetes?

Comment: Hi, you can use internal loadbalancer with VPN to expose your application to your client.

Comment: Could you please provide any reference just in case if you have any.

Comment: Hi, [On Google](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing) and [On Azure](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49577)

Comment: In simple words, You use VPN to allow your client to access the cluster then you use an internal load balancer to expose the application.

Comment: Are you using your cluster on Google , Amazon or Azure ?

Comment: I am using Azure

Comment: For Azure, If you want to use internal loadbalaner , You need to use `annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: 'true'`  in your service manifest.

Comment: Just for the record ... similar annotation for creating internal loadbalancers exists also for AWS.

Comment: Thank you. But should we have something else also in place? how do i get this to be accessed only from my client network?

Comment: As far as I Know, Most of the cloud providers are using annotation to expose the service using an internal loadbalancer.

Comment: What i meant was lets say i specified `service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: 'true'` as an annotation . But how will this be accessible only from my client network. Should i get vnet in place or something?

Comment: This might give you some insight [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview)

Comment: As your cluster and your client's network are on different site, you might need to use [site-to-site-VPN](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/06/28/step-by-step-configuring-a-site-to-site-vpn-gateway-between-azure-and-on-premise/)

Answer (score 4):

With Kubernetes Nginx Ingress it is as simple as setting an annotation on your ingress object like :

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: '8.8.8.8/32'
```

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/annotations.md#whitelist-source-range

Answer (score 3):

You can as suggested make use of the VPN and create an internal LoadBalancer or you can check the [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) that I consider that Kubernetes standard way to implement your solution.

> By default, if no policies exist in a namespace, then all ingress and egress traffic is allowed to and from pods in that namespace. The following examples let you change the default behavior in that namespace.

You will need to create a NetworkPolicy Resource, in the spec you will have to describe the behaviour making use of the available fields, I recommend you to check the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#prerequisites) to retrieve more info regarding the structure.

PolicyTypes:

- ...
- **ingress**: Each NetworkPolicy may include a list of whitelist ingress rules. Each rule allows traffic which matches both the from and ports sections. The example policy contains a single rule, which matches traffic on a single port, from one of three sources, the first specified via an ipBlock, the second via a namespaceSelector and the third via a podSelector.
- ...

> Keep in mind that in order to implement them you need to use a
>   networking solution which supports **NetworkPolicy**, if you just
>   create the resource without a controller to implement it will have no
>   effect.

Example of policy:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
        except:
        - 172.17.1.0/24
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          project: myproject
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: frontend
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5978
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Network Policy is nice. But, a simpler approach would be use set `ExternalIP` of the nginx ingress controller to the IP address in the client network. This exposes the services only on the client network.

Below is the sample configuration for [helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/nginx-ingress):

```
helm install --name my-ingress stable/nginx-ingress \
    --set controller.service.externalIPs=<IP address in client network>
```