# How do I make a Kubernetes service only available over a VPN?

Tags: kubernetes, service, vpn

I am setting up a web service in a deployment on a Kubernetes cluster. By default, this service seems to be accessible by anyone on the internet. Is it possible to restrict access to those on a given VPN? If so, how might one do so? Thanks.

Comment: How are you exposing your web service? ingress with loadbalancer or Loadbalancer or NodePort? Please clearly mention traffic flow.

Comment: I'm currently using Ingress with LoadBalancer, but am not wedded to that if there is a better way. Its still in proof of concept stage.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from scratch it depends a lot on your Ingress Controller and cloud provider. For example you can set second copy of your controller using a internal load balancer service rather than a public LB and then set that service and/or ingress to only allow from the IP of the VPN pods.

Deploy a new ingress controller with "LoadBalancer" in the service type and add specific annotation  for:

- AWS `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"`
- for GKE: `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"`

For example if you are using AWS check possible annotations that you can add to a Load Balancer:  [kubernetes-cloud-providers-load-balancers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/cloud-providers/#load-balancers).

Take a look: [vpn-ingress-kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255402/how-would-i-setup-kuberentes-ingress-to-for-vpn-only-access).

Check also: [services-accessible-within-private-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763859/make-services-accessible-only-from-private-network-kubernetes), [ingress-whitelisting](https://medium.com/@maninder.bindra/using-nginx-ingress-controller-to-restrict-access-by-ip-ip-whitelisting-for-a-service-deployed-to-bd5c86dc66d6).